# How to split a message do some extra processing on one of them and aggregate them back

Tags: apache-camel

I need to configure some camel routes based on some configuration files.

All configured routes will need to split a message into one or two sub messages then do some JMS integration work on the first one and then aggregate together the JMS reply with the optional second message. In a simplified picture it will look like below:

```
message -- > split  --> message 1 --> JMS request/reply --> aggregate --> more processing
                   \--> message 2                      /
```

The aggregation will be done on completion size which I am able to know upfront if it is going to be 1 or 2 depending of the route meta data. When the second message is present no other processing is needed before being merged back with the JMS reply.

Si in short I need a split followed by a routing followed by an aggregation which is quite a common pattern. The only particularity is is that in case the second split message is present I don't need to do anything on it before aggregating it back.

In java DSL it will looks something like this:

```
from("direct:abc")
    // The splitter below  will set the JmsIntegration flag
    .split().method(MySplitter.class, "split")
    .choice()
        .when(header("JmsIntegration"))
            .inOut("jms:someQueue"))
        .otherwise()
            // what should I have on here?
            .to(???)
    .end()
    .aggregate(...)to(...);
```

So my questions would be:

1. What should I put on the otherwise branch?

   What I need in fact is an `if`: if the split message needs JMS go to JMS and then move to aggregator if it is not just go straight to the aggregator. I am considering creating a dummy processor which will actually do nothing but this seems to me a naive approach.
2. Am I on a wrong path. If so what would be the alternative

   Initially I was thinking about a message enricher but I would not like to sent the original message to the JMS
3. I also considered putting my aggregation strategy inside my splitter but again I could not put it all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off your post it looks like you are trying to have the return of your enrichment merge with the original message, but you want to send a custom message to the jms endpoint.  I would recommend storing your original message in either a bean or a cache or something of the sort, leveraging all of your conversions with camel and then have your aggregation strategy leverage your storage to return your desired format.

```
from("direct:abc")
    .split().method(MySplitter.class, "split")
        .choice()
            .when(header("JmsIntegration"))
                .beanRef("MyStorageBean", "storeOriginal")
                .convertBodyTo(MyJmsFormat.class)
                //This aggregation strategy could have a reference 
                //to your storage bean and retrieve the instance
                .enrich("jms:someQueue", myCustomAggreationStrategyInstance)
            .otherwise()
         .end()
    .aggregate(...)
    .to("direct:continueProcessing");
```

Option #2: Based off of your comment saying you needed the "original message that the direct:abc endpoint received this can be simplified a lot. In this example we can use camel's existing Original message store to retrieve the message that was passed into direct:abc.  If Your message after the split has a JmsIntegration header we will convert the body to the desired format for the jms call, leverage the enrich statement to make the jms call and a custom aggregator that gives you access to the message used to call the jms endpoint, the message that came back, and the original message direct:abc has.  If your flow does not have a JmsIntegration header the message will go to the Otherwise statement in your route which does no additional processing before ending the choice statement and then the spit messages are aggregated back together with whatever custom strategy you need.

```
from("direct:abc")
    .split().method(MySplitter.class, "split")
        .choice()
            .when(header("JmsIntegration"))
                .convertBodyTo(MyJmsFormat.class)
                //See aggregationStrategy sample below
                .enrich("jms:someQueue", myAggStrat)
            .otherwise()
                //Non JmsIntegration header messages come here, 
                //but receive no work and are passed on.
         .end()
    .aggregate(...)
    .to("direct:continueProcessing");

//Your Custom Aggregator
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    //This logic will retrieve the original message passed into direct:abc
    Message originalMessage =(Message)exchange.getUnitOfWork().getOriginalInMessage();
    //TODO logic for manipulating your exchanges and returning the desired result
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt but I think this won't work. The message you pass to the storage bean is the one already split not the original one. I accept that using a storage to save the original then extracting the data you want to sent to jms with `convertBodyTo` bean and then have another processor that will join the jms reply back into the original stored message will work. However this look less like camel and add some embedded storage complexity which I would like to avoid. In your solution it is still unclear what will happen with the second message taking the otherwise way; main reason I posted this q

Comment: Julian,  I reworked my answer based off of your feedback.  It should be much more elegant for handling the original message received by direct:adc

Comment: Thanks Matt. This will do it. What I did not know is that if you have an empty `otherwise()` the message will be passed on in its original state. I was a bit confused by [this Fuse ESB doco](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB/4.3.1/html/Implementing_Enterprise_Integration_Patterns/files/MsgSys-Router.html). My final solution is a bit different with conversion happening inside the splitter and using a request reply as the receiver of my request is outside the JVM but this does not make your solution less valuable. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You said you considered using Enricher, but you don't want to send raw message. You can resolve this neatly by using a pre-JMS route:

```
from("direct:abc")
    .enrich("direct:sendToJms", new MyAggregation());
    .to("direct:continue");

from("direct:sendToJms")
    // do marshalling or conversion here as necessary
    .convertBodyTo(MyJmsRequest.class)
    .to("jms:someQueue");

public class MyAggregation implements AggregationStrategy {

    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange original, Exchange resource) {
        MyBody originalBody = original.getIn().getBody(MyBody.class);
        MyJmsResponse resourceResponse = resource.getIn().getBody(MyJmsResponse.class);
        Object mergeResult = ... // combine original body and resource response
        original.getIn().setBody(mergeResult);
        return original;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this will work very nice indeed.

Answer (score -1):

Splitter automatically aggregates split exchanges back together. However, default (since 2.3) aggregation strategy is to return the original exchange. You can easily override the default strategy with your own by specifying it directly on the Splitter. Furthermore, if you don't have an alternative flow for your Choice, then it's much easier to use Filter. Example:

```
from("direct:abc")
    .split().method(MySplitter.class, "split").aggregationStrategy(new MyStrategy())
        .filter(header("JmsIntegration"))
            .inOut("jms:someQueue"))
        .end()
    .end()
    .to(...);
```

You still need to implement `MyStrategy` to combine the two messages.

Comment: I don't see how this solves my problem to put together a first split message after some JMS integration with a second split one which has no processing at all. In your example moth split messages get processed by the same MyOrderService bean which is totally different than my case

Comment: @Julian, I've updated the example to use your original code for more clarity. Also I've added a suggestion to use Filter, which is probably the main thing that you're looking for.

Comment: @AntonKoscejev  This won't work for the requested use case.  You are aggregating immediately after split. So a single message is hitting the filter.  If you moved the aggregate process to the end, then you are throwing out messages without the JmsIntegration header which need to be aggregated.  You don't manage a custom format needed for the Jms enrichment and you aren't managing the need of the original message.

Comment: @MatthewFontana I don't understand what you're saying in regards to a single message hitting the filter. Filter ensures that only one message hits JMS endpoint, which is what was requested. The other message will not hit JMS, but will still continue being routed right after filter end.

Comment: @AntonKoscejev The filter will drop the message from the flow completely.  If you want code to execute on some messages but not all of them you need to use a choice statement.

Comment: @MatthewFontana That simply isn't true, filter does no such thing. Perhaps you're confusing it with stop(). Both are described here: http://camel.apache.org/message-filter.html

Try it out for yourself. Filter only applies to everything until its end. If there's no end explicitly specified, the end of the current route applies and Exchange continues to be routed after the current route.

Comment: @AntonKoscejev interesting ok I definitely had a misconception on that.  That could definitely clean up a line or two of code.  I should double check if I can leverage that in some of my existing solutions.  Thanks for the clarification